# Search Button using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This code suppose to be looking for keywords from another sheet. It works fine, but I have to type the exact work from other sheets. How can I improve it to make it only search for key words. For example, if I want to search for Red Car, I only want to type Red.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
totalsheets = Worksheets.Count
mykeyword = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(2, 8).Value
For i = 1 To totalsheets

If Worksheets(i).Name <> "MasterSheet" Then
lastrow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow
If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value = mykeyword Then
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Activate
lastrow = Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value =   Worksheets(i).Name
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 2).Value
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 3).Value
Worksheets("MasterSheet").Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 4).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value = mykeyword`

try:
`If Instr(Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value, mykeyword) > 0`

Comment: `InStr` will work, but should have the optional `Compare` parameter specified as `VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare` for a case-insensitive match.

Comment: You are the best!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Range.Find` for this, instead of nesting loops.

> ```
> If Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value = mykeyword Then
> ```

You're doing a strict string equality here. With the default comparison mode (`Option Compare Binary`), that's a case-sensitive equality test.

You want a case-insensitive partial match: the `=` operator won't cut it. The `Like` operator supports wildcards that are more suitable.

```
If LCase(Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value) Like "*" & LCase(mykeyword) & "*" Then
```

With `LCase`, you compare the lowercase representation of each cell against the lowercase representation of the search term. That works, but isn't ideal.

Extract the comparison code into its own public function in a separate module, and specify `Option Compare Text` at the top of that module:

```
Option Explicit ' always.
Option Compare Text ' makes string comparisons case-insensitive
Option Private Module ' prevent exposing public functions as UDFs

Public Function IsPartialMatch(ByVal value As String, ByVal term As String) As Boolean
    IsPartialMatch = value Like "*" & term & "*"
End Function
```

Now you can do this:

```
If IsPartialMatch(Worksheets(i).Cells(j, 1).Value, mykeyword) Then
```

---

**Alternative (better) approach**

With `Range.Find` instead, you can eliminate the nested loops, and only keep the outer one that's iterating the worksheets; `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find what you're looking for, so `If Not (result) Is Nothing Then` is all you need:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'todo: give that button a meaningful name

    Dim masterSheet As Workshet
    Set masterSheet = Worksheets("MasterSheet")

    Dim mykeyword As String
    mykeyword = masterSheet.Cells(2, 8).Value

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If Not sheet Is masterSheet Then

            Dim result As Range
            Set result = sheet.Range("A:A").Find(mykeyword, LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not result Is Nothing Then
                Dim lastRow As Long
                With masterSheet
                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = sheet.Name
                    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = sheet.Cells(result.Row, 2).Value
                    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = sheet.Cells(result.Row, 3).Value
                    .Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = sheet.Cells(result.Row, 4).Value
                End With
            End If

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that columns 3 and 4 seem to be reversed between the master sheet and whatever sheet contains the search result - verify that this is correct, and consider adding a justificative comment.

Comment: @Jhn see edit; using `Range.Find` you can eliminate the `j` loop entirely

Comment: I am a little confused about your code, how can I add it to my code?

Comment: @Jhn see edit - I further cleaned things up, and declared all variables (always add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module)